# Submission and receiving ajax form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a php script, only for learning purposes. I would like to use on my web app ajax form. Never did it, this is testing php script. So I would like to send via ajax form name and password, in php script will be checked if its correct and it will return either success(when login and password correct) or error(when no match). My problem is how to send it and receive it correctly in js or jQuery. Anyone who could help me maybe with better idea and/or better secure function of doing this?

I found on stackoverflow and tryed this script:

```
    //bind an event handler to the submit event for your login form
    $('#login_form').live('submit', function (e) {

        //cache the form element for use in this function
        var $this = $(this);

        //prevent the default submission of the form
        e.preventDefault();

        //run an AJAX post request to your server-side script, $this.serialize() is the data from your form being added to the request
        $.post($this.attr('action'), $this.serialize(), function (responseData) {

        //in here you can analyze the output from your server-side script (responseData) and validate the user's login without leaving the page
});
});
```

And I was wondering if in php script it could work like this?:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET["name"];
$password = $_GET["password"];

if($username="*****" && $password==********)
{
header('Location:http://*****************/jaz/imes/index.html?login="success"');
}else{
header('Location:http://*****************/jaz/imes/index.html?login="error"');
}
?>
```

And as I said this is just a test script just for learning more about it.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated.  Use `.on()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, try to use on() method if you're using jQuery 1.8+
Another thing is that you should set the session for that user in the PHP script, then redirect the user using the js:

jQuery:

```
$('#login_form').on('submit', function(){
        $.post($this.attr('action'), $this.serialize(), function (responseData) {
            if(responseData == 'success'){
                window.location = "userpanel.php"
            }else{
                alert('NO MATCHES');
            }
        });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// VALIDATING HERE, in db maybe?
if($username == 'blah' && $password == 'blah'){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "failed";  
}

?>
```

And in your HTML form you need to have 2 inputs with IDs as "username" and "password" so the above code could work.

Comment: Note that he also changed $_GET to $_POST since you are POSTING your values to the php script.